# LMMS is not working with VSTs

Tags: wine, lmms

So my LMMS (which is running from the .AppImage) doesn't work when i try adding VSTs to it. I realized then it's because the plugins doesn't work with my wine (version 9.0) thats why it doesn't work with LMMS. After searching how to install the 5.13 version of wine, i instead found this: https://lmms.io/forum/viewtopic.php?p=71341. Instead of using the linux install, DiViNiTY Studio got a 5.13 wine, ran LMMS in there. Now it works, but the problem is that the LMMS from windows runs slow in my computer and i don't know why wine 5.13 can't install my favorite plugins which can only be installed in .exe files.

Does somebody here know how can i run LMMS from windows faster or
force LMMS from linux to use the separate version of wine in my computer?